# How to understand if there is occurrence of a symbol in expression and make it be null if yes?

Tags: symbolic

I have a table of frequences `W={w1,w1,w2,w2}` and a function `E[i_]:=Exp[I*W[[i]]*t]`. I'd really like to write such function that `EEEE[i,j,k,l]:=E[i]*Conjugate[E[j]]*E[k]*Conjugate[E[l]]` if there's  no dependence on `t` after calculation otherwise `EEEE[i,j,k,l]:=0`
In fact function is more complicated  but here I represented minimal example.

P.S. `W` is entirely real as well as `t`.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Are you looking for `FreeQ`?

Comment: Thx, lad. It helped me!